# Div and table width won't stick to it's original form and will grow out of line

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt

I have created a html using XSLT and XML, and transformed it with java and my problem is:
I've created some fields to be populated but if i insert more text than the box size it will grow in lenght instead of height and i don't want it to grow in  width, i want it to be exactly what i set.

```
Here is the code :
......
    <xsl:template name="bodyGEO">
     <table width="770" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" >
      <tr height="10"><td/></tr>
      <tr>
       <td valign="center" width="770" colspan="2">
        <table width="770" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
          <tr>
           <td width="385">
           <b>
            <xsl:variable name="id" select="//Product/Content/Resource/Data/TextElement[@clientCode='cme_cmb_geo_tit_1']/@elementId "/>
            <xsl:variable name="max_word_count" select="//Product/Content/Resource/Data/TextElement[@clientCode='cme_cmb_geo_tit_1']/@max_word_count"/>
            <DIV id="webedit" formid="{$id}"  max_word_count="{$max_word_count}" comment="Title" width="385" style="background-color:#bfbfbf; max-width:385;">
             <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="//Product/Content/Resource/Data/TextElement[@clientCode='cme_cmb_geo_tit_1']"/>
            </DIV>
           </b>
           </td>
          <!-- <xsl:if test="$StyleSheet!='webedit'">
            <td style="text-align:left;" width="10" align="left"> <b>- </b></td>
           </xsl:if>-->
           <td width="385">
            <xsl:variable name="id" select="//Product/Content/Resource/Data/TextElement[@clientCode='cme_cmb_geo_sub_1']/@elementId "/>
            <xsl:variable name="max_word_count" select="//Product/Content/Resource/Data/TextElement[@clientCode='cme_cmb_geo_sub_1']/@max_word_count"/>
             <DIV id="webedit" formid="{$id}"  max_word_count="{$max_word_count}" comment="SubTitle" width="385" style="background-color:#bfbfbf; align:left;">
              <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="//Product/Content/Resource/Data/TextElement[@clientCode='cme_cmb_geo_sub_1']"/>
             </DIV>
           </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
       </td>
      </tr>
.......
```

I try to set a max-width,but it won't accept it... is the another way or what's wrong with this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the `table-layout` style on the `table` element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout

```
table-layout: fixed;
```

> Fixed:
>   Table and column widths are set by the widths of table and col
>   elements or by the width of the first row of cells. Cells in
>   subsequent rows do not affect column widths.
>
> Under the "fixed" layout method, the entire table can be rendered once
>   the first table row has been downloaded and analyzed. This can speed
>   up rendering time over the "automatic" layout method, but subsequent
>   cell content may not fit in the column widths provided. Any cell that
>   has content that overflows uses the overflow property to determine
>   whether to clip the overflow content.

Also from http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_table-layout.asp:

> Fixed:
>   "The horizontal layout only depends on the table's width and the width
>   of the columns, not the contents of the cells"